# Geolocator forceAndroidLocationManager TimeoutException

Tags: flutter, dart, location, android-location

When I fetch the user's location using `Geolocator` package

```
Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
          forceAndroidLocationManager: false,
          timeLimit: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000));
```

It works without errors, but when **forceAndroidLocationManager** is set to **true**
it gives always TimeoutException.

i want **forceAndroidLocationManager** to be **true**
i checked all permissions and service enable
Flutter 2.10.4
Geolocator 8.2.0